# Get browser height from within a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I'm using Moodle: [image: moddle]

I am trying to run some Javascript from within the frame to get the browser window height, so I can alert the user if they are using a less then optimal browser size.

I'v tried things like:

```
window.top.document.body.offsetHeight
document.documentElement.clientHeight
$(document).height()
$(window).height()
```

But they all give static heights which never change when I resize the browser.

Oh and it has to work in IE8.

Comment: `which never change when I resize the browser`....That's a responsive schema, you would need to be within the scope of `$(window).on('resize', function(){ console.log($(window).height()); });`

Comment: I meant, between refreshing the browser. I had setup an alert to tell me the height on load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the `parent` property of the iFrame window:

Run this code from within the iFrame, it will return the height of the parent window:

```
$(window.parent).height();
```

However, if you're using jQuery 1.8.0 this may not work if your browser is in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). As of jQuery 1.8.0, the command `$(window).height()` stopped working for Internet Explorer in quirks mode and they [don't plan to fix it](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12310).

If you're using jQuery 1.8.0, use this slight variation instead:

```
$(window.parent.document).height();
```

This will ensure cross-browser support, even in IE quirks mode ;)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp

Answer (score 1):

One simple Solution will be to call a parent document function from iframe returning document height

**Iframe Javascript** :

```
alert(top.getDocHeight());
```

**Main Document Javascript** :

```
function getDocHeight()
{
    return $(window).height();

}
```